# call to a member function assign role() on boolean

Tags: laravel, permisos, users-roles

Estoy usan Spatie en mi aplicación de Laravel y Me sale ese problema, y nose que falta o que estoy haciendo mal.

```
public function run()
{
    Permission::create(['name' => 'peliculas.index']);
    Permission::create(['name' => 'peliculas.edit']);
    Permission::create(['name' => 'peliculas.show']);
    Permission::create(['name' => 'peliculas.create']);
    Permission::create(['name' => 'peliculas.destroy']);

    //Admin
    $admin = Role::create(['name' => 'Admin']);

    $admin->givePermissionTo([
        'peliculas.index',
        'peliculas.edit',
        'peliculas.show',
        'peliculas.create',
        'peliculas.destroy'
    ]);
    //$admin->givePermissionTo('peliculas.index');
    //$admin->givePermissionTo(Permission::all());

    //Guest
    $guest = Role::create(['name' => 'Guest']);

    $guest->givePermissionTo([
        'peliculas.index',
        'peliculas.show'
    ]);

    //User Admin
    $user = User::find(1); //Italo Morales
    $user->assignRole('Admin');
}
```

y siempre me sale este problema
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No parece ser el mismo código que compartes, puesto que aparece un llamado al método save() en el mensaje de error, y en el código que nos muestras, no.

Comment: si el save() lo borre cuando saque la captura, pero sin el save y con el save da el mismo error. Nose porque